# Audio through EarPods disabled when plugging in a monitor

Tags: audio

Every time the monitor is disconnected and connected, the audio icons on my Touch Bar go black and I have to unplug and plug back in my EarPods for it to turn back into white icons.

I use the Hyperdrive to connect to a monitor using HDMI.

[image: Hyperdrive]

Is this a feature/setting or a bug?

MacBook Pro 2017, macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Comment: Is your monitor plugged in with a HDMI cable and does it have built-in HDMI speakers?

Comment: @user158589 It is plugged in using a Hyperdrive (2017 model does not have a direct HDMI input). The monitor does not have build in speakers.

Comment: Okay, then it's not a HDMI monitor taking over the sound output upon connection. Sorry, as I'm on an older hardware and operating system myself, I'm unable troubleshoot further. Let's hope that someone else can tap into this issue as it's likely to be related to the more recent builds.